# CSS Menu - LI / A width

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I'm creating a CSS drop down menu which is going well so far, however I have a problem with the width the `<li>` or `<a>` in the sub menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cbe8/

If you hover over 'About Us' you'll all of the sub menu links are different widths. I've tried setting both elements to `width: 100%` but I'm guessing the problem is something to do with the `<ul>` being absolutely positioned and not having a fixed width.

Could you please point me in the right direction to fix this.

NOTE: This probably won't work in earlier versions of IE yet, that's something I'm going to be working on next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cbe8/4/)

Set the width of it to be auto. I have also included a z-index so it renders above the other elements

HTML

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">In The News</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Resellers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>​
```

CSS

```
 body{font: 13px verdana; margin: 10px}

#main-nav ul, #main-nav ul li ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding:0;}

#main-nav ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover{background: #EEE}

#main-nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0px;}

/* This is the bit I'm having a problem with  */

#main-nav ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top:35px;
    background: lightblue;
}

#main-nav ul li ul li {white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; z-index: 999}
 ​    ​
```

Comment: This menu is going to be used on a Wordpress theme. So I can't use fixed width because I need the flexibility add longer links

Comment: All you have to do is remove the "a" before your selector

Comment: So that you are applying it to the li element, not the a

Comment: great... but there's one more problem... do you have to use the .submenu class? Wordpress doesn't render menu's with classes and I'd rather not have to use custom menu structures

Comment: No, if have updated my answer. Here is a link to the solution http://jsfiddle.net/8Cbe8/5/

Comment: Haha no problem, glad to help :) Im much to English for this flattery

Answer (score 0):

try using: `width: auto;` instead of `width: 100%;`

Comment: This makes the `<li>` a nice width, but the `<a>` does't span the width. I've tried making the `<a>` 100% & auto but doesn't work